# Homework - Big O Notation and Calculating Time

Tags: algorithm

let's say I have an algorithm that takes 0.5ms for n = 20, and I want to figure out how long it takes if n = 40 for O(n^2).

To my understanding, the procedure is as follows:

t = 0.5 * (40^2/20^2)

But why is this? I don't understand the mechanics behind this. I know that Big O is an upper bound, and for any n, its an output of some number of instructions. But calculating the time isn't making sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> let's say I have an algorithm that takes 0.5ms for n = 20, and I want to figure out how long it takes if n = 40 for O(n^2).

Unfortunately, you can infer about the behavior for *n = 40* almost nothing.

The statement that the algorithm is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* means that there exists some constant *c > 0* for which, for large enough *n*, the running time is not larger than *c n<sup>2</sup>*. Consequently, you do not know if 20, 40, or 4,000,000 falls into "large enough" *n*, and even if it does, you can only know that it is bounded from above by something.

> But calculating the time isn't making sense.

That's a logical conclusion, unfortunately.

---

**Edit**

Thanks to the excellent comment by Anmol Singh Jaggi (many thanks!), here is the figure to which he linked that illustrates the problem

[image]

Comment: Nice answer Ami! You might want to add [this image](https://s14.postimg.org/5glrz8ogx/a.jpg) as a part of the answer to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Awesome picture! Definitely makes the relationship easier to see

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Just wanted to add again what an excellent figure you made - many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped!